# Custom Gradle Logging

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, buildkite

My company uses [Buildkite](https://buildkite.com) for our CI services. When the CI server triggers a build, all logs from the build are sent to Buildkite and made available through the UI. This is useful since it allows us to check how a build failed.

Buildkite has a feature which creates collapsible groups from logs formatted like:

```
--- Compiling
logs after this point will be in a collapsible group named 'Compiling'

--- Testing
logs after this point will be in a collapsible group named 'Testing'
```

How can I add custom logging to a gradle build which will output these 'groups'? I'd like to have a group for compiling/assembling, one for running unit tests, etc.

I've considered adding tasks which perform the logging and making them dependencies of the built-in tasks, but I'm not sure how to do that, or if it's a good idea in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Gradle 2.12 and whipped up an example from the [Logging doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html). The example does not use Android Studio nor BuildKite, but I believe this will help with the fundamental question.

Given a simple `build.gradle` file for a typical Java project:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

compileJava << { println "TRACER example log from compileJava" }
compileTestJava << { println "TRACER example log from compileTestJava" }

test << { println "TRACER example log from test" }
```

and an `init.gradle` file:

```
useLogger(new CustomEventLogger())

class CustomEventLogger extends BuildAdapter implements TaskExecutionListener {

    public void beforeExecute(Task task) {
        if (task.name ==~ "compileJava") {
            println "--- Compiling"
        } else if (task.name == "test") {
            println "--- Testing"
        }
    }

    public void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState state) {}

    public void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {}
}
```

then this command-line:

```
$ gradle -I init.gradle test
```

yields this output:

```
--- Compiling
TRACER example log from compileJava
TRACER example log from compileTestJava
--- Testing
TRACER example log from test
```